# Long initial page load on firefox/chrome using faye/nodejs due to transport layer /meta/connect call

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, google-chrome, faye

I'm having a strange issue with faye/nodejs where the page appears to be loading for a long time on an initial page load due to a /meta/connect call.  This page load appears to last for exactly 45s (which is the value of the timeout set on the server)

Here are the details of the call:

The call in question is the following:

RAW GET:
https://MYURL.com:8089/notifications?message=%5B%7B%22channel%22%3A%22%2Fmeta%2Fconnect%22%2C%22clientId%22%3A%220c3gocq1rwi3sl0dskn4u00e8wj7%22%2C%22connectionType%22%3A%22callback-polling%22%2C%22id%22%3A%225%22%7D%5D&jsonp=__jsonp3__

params:
jsonp: __jsonp3__
message: [{"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"0c3gocq1rwi3sl0dskn4u00e8wj7","connectionType":"callback-polling","id":"5"}]

response:
__jsonp3__([{"id":"5","clientId":"0c3gocq1rwi3sl0dskn4u00e8wj7","channel":"/meta/connect","successful":true,"advice":{"reconnect":"retry","interval":0,"timeout":45000}}]);

I've tried it without SSL, but the problem still persists, so it doesn't appear to be related to that.

The page is completely responsive during this time, but it's obviously an issue for my customers as they just see the loading bar in ff or chrome and they end up waiting the full 45 seconds for it to stop before proceeding.  Any help in debugging or mitigating this issue is appreciated; possibly making the initial connect call asynchronous so it doesn't trigger on an initial page load?

I've also posted on the faye google group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/faye-users/xZI4adt3DpA%5B1-25%5D

But I have not gotten a reply yet, though it does seem that I am not the only one with this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case any future googlers stumble on this topic:  the issue in question has been resolved in the newer versions of Faye.  There are some further details on the google group link in my original question - the issue should be fixed as of faye 0.8.4 (currently 0.8.6)

I can confirm that this fixed the issue for me, I no longer see any timeouts on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not `end()`ing the response you're sending out, so your server is keeping the connection open.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?  This is occurring on page load, so the client has not sent any messages at this time, and the server is also not sending any messages.

On the client, all I'm doing is instantiating Faye, and subscribing to a channel.  On the server, it's just accepting the subscription.  Where do I need to call end()?  On the client or server?  I expect the solution to be something like this, but a little additional clarification would help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When sending to channel /meta/connect add this to your params:

```
"advice":{"timeout": 0}
```

So your connect message should looks like that:

```
{"channel":"/meta/connect","clientId":"0c3gocq1rwi3sl0dskn4u00e8wj7","connectionType":"callback-polling","id":"5","advice":{"timeout":0}}
```

You can follow my solution starting with this [place](https://github.com/faye/faye/blob/master/lib/faye/protocol/server.rb#LC170):

```
# server.rb
@engine.connect(response['clientId'], message['advice']) do |events|
  callback.call([response] + events)
end

...

# proxy.rb
def connect(client_id, options = {}, &callback)
  debug 'Accepting connection from ?', client_id
  @engine.ping(client_id)
  conn = connection(client_id, true)
  conn.connect(options, &callback)
  @engine.empty_queue(client_id)
end

...

# connection.rb
def connect(options, &block)
  options = options || {}
  timeout = options['timeout'] ? options['timeout'] / 1000.0 : @engine.timeout

  set_deferred_status(:deferred)
  callback(&block)

  begin_delivery_timeout
  begin_connection_timeout(timeout)
end
```

These methods are called when message comes to /meta/connect channel.

Comment: How do I add this to the /meta/connect parameters?  It seems to be an automatic action, and the documentation for Faye is somewhat sparse.


If I try the following: var client = new Faye.Client('http://localhost:8000/faye', {
    timeout: 15, advice: { timeout: 0 } 
});

I do not see the advice object in the parameters of the offending ajax request.  In the response, advice.timeout remains at 10 (the value of the current server timeout)

Comment: This appears to be resolved now with the new versions of Faye.

Comment: Edited my answer, hope you'll get my idea.

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue after James Coglan updated faye, and I'm also using node and not ruby for the faye server, but your solution looks useful and I hope it helps a future visitor.